# Netty and JDK version confliction

Tags: java, netty

I am studying netty tool using a tutorial, but I have met a question which I think it maybe be related with the version of Netty jar package and JDK.
Now, my jdk is 1.8 and Netty version is netty-all-4.0.0 Final.jar that I downloaded  from the netty offical website.

The following is the error code, **which I have used a comment followed the error line**. Because I don't know how to highlight in code segment, you maybe need to notice the comment carefully, fortunately just two lines.

```
    EventLoopGroup pGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();    
    EventLoopGroup cGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();    
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

    b.group(pGroup, cGroup)                             
    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)              
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024)             
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 32*1024)           
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 32*1024)           
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)           
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {        // there is an error, which indicates that the generic <SocketChannel> is not a valid substitute according the eclipse automatic prompt

        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel sc) throws Exception {
            sc.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());            // there are two errors about the pipeline method and ServerHander construtor
        }

    });

    ChannelFuture cf1 = b.bind().sync();                

    cf1.channel().closeFuture().sync();                 

    pGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    cGroup.shutdownGracefully();
```

Comment: that cant be a problem with jdk

Comment: I think so, because the code is very old, his jdk version may older than me. And the second error line whose second error about the handler is not an error, because I don't define corresponding class yet.

Comment: you know try installing another jdk in my pc that would not be priority choice for me. I will try to fix it.

Comment: i am using netty 4 with jdk 8, no problems

Comment: But netty 4 has many branches and which version you chose? Did you use it like what I have shown for you?

Comment: Yes, 4.0.4 final

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you imported the wrong `SocketChannel` here. This needs to be `io.netty.channel.socket.SocketChannel` but you most likely used the `java.nio. SocketChannel`.

Comment: Sorry, exactly I still have a problem, which is that ChannelHandlerAdapter do not have a channelRead method and only have handlerAdd and handlerRemove methods to Override when I define the ServerHandler class to handler the asynchronized messages from Client.

Comment: You want to use ChannelInboundHandler